# Getting errors with my SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble getting my SQL table to work. It keeps giving me an error that it cannot drop tables due to not permission or not exisiting. And it's telling me that there's an invalid table as well.

I currently have:

```
drop table Orders
drop table Item
drop table Supplier
drop table Staff
drop table Customers
drop table Ingredient



CREATE TABLE Supplier(
SupplierNo CHAR(7) PRIMARY KEY,
SupplierName CHAR(25),
SupplierAddress VARCHAR(25),
SupplierPhone CHAR(10),
SupplierContactPerson CHAR (35)
)
go


CREATE TABLE Item (
ItemNo      CHAR(7)     PRIMARY KEY,
ItemName    CHAR(10),
ItemType    CHAR(10),
Price       DEC(3,2),
IngredientCode CHAR (5),

FOREIGN KEY(IngredientCode) REFERENCES Ingredient(IngredientCode)
)
go

CREATE TABLE Staff (
EmployeeID CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
FirstName  CHAR(10),
LastName CHAR(10),
PostalAddress VARCHAR(MAX),
ContactNumber CHAR (10),
RateOfPay     MONEY,
EmployementStatus CHAR(25)
)

CREATE TABLE Customers (
CustomerID CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
CustomerFN CHAR(25),
CustomerLN CHAR(25),
CustomerPhN CHAR(11),
CAddress VARCHAR (25)
)
go

CREATE TABLE Ingredient(
IngredientCode CHAR (5) PRIMARY KEY,
IngredientName CHAR(25),
IngredientDesc VARCHAR(max),
CurrentStockLevel CHAR(3),
PreviousStockLevel CHAR(3),
SuggestedStockLevel CHAR(3),
SupplierNo CHAR(7),
Supplied DATE(),

FOREIGN KEY(SupplierNo) REFERENCES Supplier(SupplierNo)
)

CREATE TABLE Orders(
OrderNo CHAR(7),
OrderDate DATE(),
CustomerNo CHAR(4) FOREIGN KEY,
EmployeeID CHAR(3) FOREIGN KEY,
ItemNo      CHAR(7) FOREIGN KEY,
TypeOfOrder CHAR(10),
TotalAmount MONEY(),
PaymentMethod CHAR(10),
OrderStatus CHAR(10)

FOREIGN KEY CustomerNo, EmployeeID, ItemNo
REFERENCES Customer(CustomerNo), Staff(EmployeeID), Item(ItemNo)
)
```

It seems like a very simple problem to have, but I'm not even sure what it means with me having no permission or the table not existing at all...

Comment: In SQL, statements need to be terminated with `;`. Also: which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Regardless of the actual DBMS being used: `CustomerNo CHAR(4) FOREIGN KEY,` is wrong. You need to specify the _target_ of that foreign key, e.g. `CustomerNo CHAR(4) references customers`. Please read the manual of your DBMS for the correct syntax

Comment: So something like this? 

<code>
CREATE TABLE Orders(
OrderNo CHAR(7),
OrderDate DATE(),
CustomerNo CHAR(4) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(CustomerNo),
EmployeeID CHAR(3) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Staff(EmployeeID),
ItemNo  CHAR(7) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Item(ItemNo),
TypeOfOrder CHAR(10),
TotalAmount MONEY(),
PaymentMethod CHAR(10),
OrderStatus CHAR(10)
</code>

Answer (score 0):

You create constraint, before create table Ingredient

FOREIGN KEY(IngredientCode) REFERENCES Ingredient(IngredientCode)